# Create a new String with the characters as Key by each Value from LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, key, linkedhashmap

```
public class StringManagement {  
    private String str;
    private Map<Character, List<Integer>> lettersHistogram = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    //private Map<Character, Integer> numCount = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer();

    public void convertToOldString(){
        String oldString;
        char emptySlotsOfString[] = new char[lettersHistogram.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<emptySlotsOfString.length; i++){
            Arrays.fill(emptySlotsOfString, ' ');
        }

}
```

I need to create a function that will read the characters with the location information, from the structure stored, will recompose the string back to its original form situation by placing the necessary blanks and then it will print it.

for example if i add the string "HELLO SAMOS!" right now returns me
{H=[0], E=[1], L=[2, 3], O=[4, 9], S=[6, 10], A=[7], M=[8], !=[11]}
it saves every character with each position in the linkedhashmap.

I just thought that i have to create an empty char[] table that will fill with spaces ' ' same length as the size of the map and replace the ' ' with characters from the map by each value.. please some help..

Comment: You almost did a good job on your first question. Even better would be if you had included what behavior you observe with your code - errors, unexpected output, etc.. 
That being said: Shouldn't your emptySlotsOfString-array be (at least) as big as the highest index+1 in your map and not only as big as your historgram, because your array is only 8 long while your string's length is 12.

Answer (score 0):

The length of the initial `String` is **not** equal to the size of the `Map` since each character might be encountered multiple times. To calculate the string's length you need to add up the sizes of all the lists of indices in the Map.

```
public int getLength() {
    int length = 0;
    for (List<Integer> indices : lettersHistogram.values()) {
        length += indices.size();
    }
    return length;
}
```

Then to restore the initial string, you can iterate over the entries of the `Map` using a nested `for`-loop. In the inner loop, iterate over the values (i.e. a list of indices) of each entry and assign the Key of the entry (character) to every corresponding index in the array.

Finally, use constructor [`String(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(char%5B%5D)) to turn the char array into a `String`.

```
public String convertToOldString() {
    char[] chars = new char[getLength()];
    for (var entry : lettersHistogram.entrySet()) {
        for (int index : entry.getValue())
        chars[index] = entry.getKey();
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```